# How can I close my own question?

Tags: support

I asked a question on Super User, then realised it was more suitable for Server Fault so asked there instead and got a great answer, but the question on Super User is still open.

I recognise I should have asked on Server Fault first so that's my bad, but how do I close my Super User question?

Comment: Just click the delete button under the post.  Alternatively, post a link to the question and I'm sure people here will promptly help with voting to close it for you ;)

Comment: Thanks all, didn't see the delete link!

Comment: For future reference, do not post the same question on more than one site - flag for migration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it hasn't got any answers yet, just delete it yourself (you can do that for questions without upvoted answers). To get it closed you would need to flag for a moderator. But in this case there is not really any advantage to keep the duplicate on a different site, so I would just delete it.

Answer (score 5):

Flag it for moderator attention and explain what happened. A link to the question on SF wouldn't hurt.

Or, you know, click the "delete" link.